# Change Chrome tab color with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, meta-tags

In Chrome you can set the color of a tab with the meta tag:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFA000">
```

In my website, I have several sections color-coded. To make it look better, I would like to dynamically change the tab's color according to the currently opened section. I have tried doing it with jQuery:

```
$("meta[name='theme-color']").attr('content', '#455A64');
```

But it doesn't work. I would be very glad if someone can tell me if/how you can change this meta value during runtime.

Edit: After some checks I noticed that the code does change the meta tag content, but Chrome doesn't update the tab color.

Comment: Wow, had not heard of `theme-color` before (and took me a sec to realize you're talking about *Android* Chrome).

Comment: I've tested locally, but the code you've posted works as you expect. You'll need to add more details so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: As I've tried to highlight with my answer, the code as posted should work. Given your edit you still have trouble getting the effect. Can you check on your device if the plnkr link from my answer works for you? If it does, then there's probably something specific to your code/app that causes problems. If it doesn't, you may need to include your device details and Chrome / Android versions, as I'd then suspect that to be the culprit.

Comment: does not work in Chrome v106  `<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFA000">`

Answer (score 23):

For this who land on this page from Google looking for a vanilla JS solution:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="theme-color"]').setAttribute('content',  '#123456');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery code is correct. If you want to flicker the title bar and drive your users off, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Unicorns!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> 
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#FF0000">    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Unicorns are <b id="x">#FF0000</b></h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var i = 0;
            var colors = ["#FF0000", "#FFFF00", "#00FF00", "#00FFFF", "#0000FF"];
            setInterval(function() {
                var color = colors[i = i++ > 4 ? 0 : i];
                $("meta[name='theme-color']").attr('content', color);
                $("#x").text(color);
            }, 500);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested this on my Nexus 5 with Chrome 40.0.2214.89 and Android version 5.1.1, and seen it work. Not sure what to think of this type of feature yet though... :P

Not all fiddle tools will allow you to show the effect though, because I think use of iframes may prevent you from reproducing it properly. I've found that Plnkr did work though. Visiting [this demo Plnkr](http://run.plnkr.co/ViaOWi3Sf7eqQrfr/) showed the effect on abovementioned device.

Comment: Well, turns out, it doesn't work in Chrome version 44.x I downgraded to Version 39 and now it works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it doesn't work with android Chrome versions 43.x & 44.x. In other versions all the Code above works. In version 45.x it even fades from one color to the other, making it look really cool!