# make browser tab orange blink once executed specific code in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have some sctipt which I run in the specific browser tab and I'm trying to add some notification once the code 'milestone' is met.
Let's say we have a loop where:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  //some code here

  if (i == 3) {
    // when this is met I would like the current tab to start blinking 
  }
}
```

Any idea how it could be handled in js script?

Comment: *I would like the current tab to start blinking* god I hope this is impossible - I'd uninstall any browser that would allow this, and never ever visit a page that did this to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269746/change-chrome-tab-color-with-javascript-or-jquery

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: @JaromandaX this is only for debug purposes to know and highlight tab, which already executed the script

Comment: rather than the tab changing colour you could cycle background colour of the page quite easily ( or any other element )

Comment: sure, but if such a thing were possible, I'm sure not everyone would be as "responsible" about using as you appear to be

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - which would be pointless if it's not the current tab :p

Comment: Have you considered changing the favicon ...

Comment: @JaromandaX true enough if the user was not on that tab at the time!

Comment: maybe if not the tab, the browser window can blink on the windows Start tab? would it be easier to execute?

Comment: cycle the page title with a particular message perhaps

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I already add a message, just wanted to make it more obvious to see, when plenty of pages are opened :)

Answer (score 1):

What I meant by `cycling the document title` was to display some other content in a loop which gives a strobe like effect to the page tab (in Chrom & FF anyway ) - when the tab loses focus this slows but still should help draw the eye to that tab... just an idea

```
const cycletab=( chr=45, total=100, time=250 )=>{
    /*
        Flash document title
    */
    let title=document.title;
    let i=0;
    
    let tx=setInterval(()=>{
        if( i >= total && !isNaN( tx ) ) {
            document.title=title;
            clearInterval( tx );
            return false;
        }
        i++;
        
        document.title=document.title==title ? String.fromCharCode( chr ).repeat( 50 ) : title;
    }, time );          
};

cycletab();
```